# Table-Valued function - Order by is ignored in output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

We are moving from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012 and immediately noticed that all our table-valued functions no longer deliver their temp table contents in the correctly sorted order.

CODE:

```
INSERT INTO @Customer
        SELECT Customer_ID, Name,
        CASE 
            WHEN Expiry_Date < GETDATE() then 1 
            WHEN Expired = 1 then 1 
            ELSE 0
            END
        from Customer **order by Name**
```

In SQL Server 2008 this function returns the customers sorted by Name. In SQL Server 2012 it returns the table unsorted. The **"order by"** is ignored in SQL 2012.

Do we have to re-write all the functions to include a `sort_id` and then sort them when they are called in the main application or is there an easy fix??

Comment: Yes the insert still appears in the plan but is not reflected in the results.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There were two things wrong with your original approach.

1. On inserting to the table it was never guaranteed that the `ORDER BY` on the `INSERT ... SELECT ... ORDER BY` would be the order that the rows were actually inserted.
2. On selecting from it SQL Server does not guarantee that `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` will return the rows in any particular order such as insertion order anyway.

In 2012 it looks as though the behaviour has changed with respect to item 1. It now generally ignores the `ORDER BY` on the `SELECT` statement that is the source for an `INSERT`

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(number int)

INSERT INTO @T 
SELECT number
FROM master..spt_values
ORDER BY name
```

#### 2008 Plan

[image: 2008 plan]

#### 2012 Plan

[image: 2012 plan]

The reason for the change of behaviour is that in previous versions SQL Server produced one plan that was shared between executions with `SET ROWCOUNT 0` (off) and `SET ROWCOUNT N`. The sort operator was only there to ensure the correct semantics in case the plan was run by a session with a non zero `ROWCOUNT` set. The `TOP` operator to the left of it is a [`ROWCOUNT TOP`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/07/25/rowcount-top.aspx).

SQL Server 2012 now produces separate plans for the two cases so there is no need to add these to the `ROWCOUNT 0` version of the plan.

A sort may still appear in the plan in 2012 if the `SELECT` has an explicit `TOP` defined (other than `TOP 100 PERCENT`) but this still doesn't guarantee actual insertion order of rows, the plan might then have another sort after the `TOP N` is established to get the rows into clustered index order for example.

For the example in your question I would just adjust the calling code to specify `ORDER BY name` if that is what it requires.

Regarding your `sort_id` idea from [Ordering guarantees in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx) it is guaranteed when inserting into a table with `IDENTITY` that the order these are allocated will be as per the `ORDER BY` so you could also do

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE (
  Sort_Id     INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Customer_ID INT,
  Name        INT,
  Expired     BIT )

INSERT INTO @Customer
SELECT Customer_ID,
       Name,
       CASE
         WHEN Expiry_Date < Getdate() THEN 1
         WHEN Expired = 1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END
FROM   Customer
ORDER  BY Name
```

but you would still need to order by the `sort_id` in your selecting queries as there is no guaranteed ordering without that (perhaps this `sort_id` approach might be useful in the case where the original columns used for ordering aren't being copied into the table variable)

Comment: +1 I have always tought that `ORDER BY` is ignored during in `INSERT`. Knowing that this is not the case having `IDENTITY` column is usuful.

Comment: That `INSERT` does not always respect the order of the supplying statement can be shown fairly simply: a table with a integer key and arbitrary large rows, insert many rows individually in incrementing order and the clustered index is tidy, insert in arbitrary order individually and it will show some fragmentation. Now insert the same rows in one go in incrementing and the same arbitrary order (try force it with `SELECT TOP 100% ... ORDER BY`): in both cases the index is clean showing that the arbitrary order is ignored despite seeing the expected sort operation in the query plan.

Comment: Actually, you can see in the query plan an explicit sort-by-the-index-order step, after the sort-by-the-arbitrary-order step, if you inspect the query plans for the mass insert statements. You don't ask for that sort, SQL Server adds it itself to make the insert into the index more efficient. See https://pastebin.com/SVLtiRnP for an example of this in action.

Comment: @DavidSpillett Hopefully this is already mentioned in the answer `this still doesn't guarantee actual insertion order of rows, the plan might then have another sort after the TOP N is established to get the rows into clustered index order for example`. Also has this answer been linked to recently from somewhere? I noticed a few recent votes on it which seems unexpected for a 7 year old answer.

Comment: It got mentioned in a post by Brent Ozar. I didn't realise it was an older question until after I'd added my comments.

Answer (score 3):

add a column named rowno to @Customer table

```
INSERT INTO @Customer

SELECT ROW_NUMBER()over(order by Name)rowno,Customer_ID, Name,
        CASE 
            WHEN Expiry_Date < GETDATE() then 1 
            WHEN Expired = 1 then 1 
            ELSE 0
            END
from Customer
```

Comment: Thanks - we'll begin the re-development of all the procedures, functions and all the calls in the application. Who said migration would be easy.

Comment: @TanisDraven - You don't need to use `ROW_NUMBER`. You can just add an `IDENTITY` column to all tables the sort by the value of that in your outer select. See [Ordering guarantees in SQL Server...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx). I would also make the `IDENTITY` column the clustered primary key to avoid having a sort in the `SELECT` plan (though your outer queries still need to have the `ORDER BY` to get the guaranteed ordering)