# How to increment DateTime column by a second for every row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Suppose that I have this Time value: `09:00:00`

And I have a table with a column Time, and I have three records in it.

I want to update those 3 records with that time but with the Time value incremented in one second each time (for every record).

Something like this:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
1         09:00:00
2         09:00:01
3         09:00:02
```

How can I do that?

**My Solution:**

After some time working on my own solution, this is what I came up with

```
update tor1
set ColumnB = dateadd(s,tor2.inc, ColumnB)
from table1 tor1
inner join (select ColumnA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by ColumnA) as inc from table1) tor2 on tor1.ColumnA=tor2.ColumnA
```

Comment: And if we can't use `ColumnA` to order, how do you propose we know which row to add 0 seconds to, which to add 1, and which to add 2? A table is an unordered set of rows, so if you want a predictable result, you need to indicate how that order is defined.

Comment: Let's say that `ColumnA` is the PK and it is identity. Now suppose that record 2 was deleted, would you add 2 seconds to row number 3?

Comment: Are you asking yourself what your own requirements are?

Comment: I just want to add seconds (1++) to that columnB regardless the other columns. First row, same time, second row +1, third row 2, and so on

Comment: The problem is, how on earth do you define "first row" if you want us to pretend that ColumnA doesn't exist?

Comment: @Somebody So you don't care about the order at all as long as they get sequential seconds?

Comment: That is corrent @CadeRoux

Comment: @Somebody So now that you have an answer, the bavillion dollar question is WHY DO YOU WANT TO DO THIS?

Comment: @CadeRoux trying to do a logic to solve a problem using asp.net and sql :)

Comment: @Somebody OK, I'll go there.  What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve using this technique?

Comment: @CadeRoux I really appreciate your help, but I just got the answer to my problem, thank you :)

Comment: @CadeRoux This solution may be useful to someone who wants to begin to enforce a unique value for a datetime column.

Comment: @tuespetre indeed, but we may never know about this one since the OP gave little motivation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't specify any particular ordering.

For undeterministic/undocumented results you could try the quirky update approach.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    ColumnB datetime NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO table1 DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO table1 DEFAULT VALUES;

DECLARE @ColumnB datetime;

SET @ColumnB = '19000101 09:00:00';

UPDATE table1
SET @ColumnB = ColumnB = DATEADD(s, 1, @ColumnB);

SELECT *
FROM table1;

DROP TABLE table1;
```

Otherwise you will need to use a cursor or find some way of simulating `ROW_NUMBER` in 2000.

Comment: @mattedgod - It isn't documented/guaranteed though (especially fragile if relying on any kind of deterministic ordering) and should be obsolete with the fuller implementation of the `OVER` clause in later versions. An interesting article on SQL Server central about it [Solving the Running Total and Ordinal Rank Problems (Rewritten)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/). But if the OP is just setting up test data for example should be fine.

Comment: Richard is bent out of shape because your `DECLARE` line doesn't work in 2000.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - The `IDENTITY` values are guaranteed to be allocated as per the `ORDER` clause. The insert isn't guaranteed to be in any particular order. In 2012 [this shows up more as it often used to follow the `ORDER BY` just in case the plan was run with `SET ROWCOUNT N`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222043/table-valued-function-order-by-is-ignored-in-output/11231935#11231935)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version that uses a #temp table but doesn't use the unsupported quirky update (no offense Martin) and doesn't rely on magical identity ordering, which is not guaranteed (no offense Richard).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Whatever
(
  ColumnA INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  ColumnB DATETIME
);

INSERT dbo.Whatever(ColumnB) SELECT '09:00';
INSERT dbo.Whatever(ColumnB) SELECT '09:00';
INSERT dbo.Whatever(ColumnB) SELECT '09:00';
INSERT dbo.Whatever(ColumnB) SELECT '09:00';
INSERT dbo.Whatever(ColumnB) SELECT '09:00';

-- just to demonstrate a gap
DELETE dbo.Whatever WHERE ColumnA = 3;

SELECT w.ColumnA, w.ColumnB, 
  c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Whatever WHERE ColumnA < w.ColumnA)
INTO #x
 FROM dbo.Whatever AS w;

UPDATE w
  SET ColumnB = DATEADD(SECOND, x.c, w.ColumnB)
  FROM dbo.Whatever AS w
  INNER JOIN #x AS x
  ON x.ColumnA = w.ColumnA;

SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM dbo.Whatever;
```

Results:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
-------  -----------------------
1        1900-01-01 09:00:00.000
2        1900-01-01 09:00:01.000
4        1900-01-01 09:00:02.000
5        1900-01-01 09:00:03.000
```

Comment: Probably not advised for large tables due to the `SELECT COUNT(*)` subquery making it O(n^2). But otherwise a good solution ***if ColumnA is unique*** (OP hasn't stated).

Comment: OP stated it was an identity column. While that on its own doesn't guarantee uniqueness, I've only seen duplicates as a result of intentional sabotage or extreme daftness.

Comment: OP asked a question "what if ... is an identity". OP also stated under mattedgod's answer "think that column not even exists". Of course, my solution wouldn't work either in that case

Answer (score 3):

If you can assume `ColumnA` is the number of seconds you need to add (or directly proportional like your example), then you can use that.

```
UPDATE myTable SET ColumnB = DATEADD(s, (ColumnA - 1), ColumnB)
```

If not, you will need to determine the rank of each column (plenty of results on google for that) and add the rank instead.

Comment: Sadly I can't use that column as the incremental value. Moreover think that column not even exists

Comment: @Somebody What column doesn't exist? ColumnA? You included it in your example...provide a method of determining the order if it's not ColumnA, how else should we know?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2005 onwards, you can use the OVER clause to control the ordering of the updates.

```
;with T as (
    select *, rn=row_number() over (order by columnA)
    from Tbl)
update T
    set columnB = DateAdd(s, rn-1, '09:00:00');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80103/2)

For SQL Server 2000, you can use a temporary table.  Use [INSERT INTO..SELECT to guarantee](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx) the computation of the IDENTITY column.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    ColumnA int,
    ColumnB datetime NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 values (1, null);
INSERT INTO table1 values (2, getdate());
INSERT INTO table1 values (3, '02:02:02');

create table #tmp (ColumnA int, ID int identity(0,1))

insert into #tmp
select ColumnA
from table1
order by ColumnA;

update a
set ColumnB = dateadd(s,t.ID,'09:00:00')
from #tmp t
join table1 a on a.ColumnA = t.ColumnA;

select * from table1;
```

Comment: That is for a table that has an IDENTITY column defined. You are using the IDENTITY function, which is different. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q273586

Comment: I think there can also be bugs that involve parallelism and how identity values are assigned, so if you are going to rely on what you observe, please use `MAXDOP 1`. For the OP's example (three rows) this won't be an issue, but we don't really know how many rows we're talking about.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - I think Aaron's point is that the article guarantees ordering but not sequential.

Comment: Also see http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/identity-function-isn-t-reliable-for-imposing-order-on-a-result-set-43553 (regarding the IDENTITY() function).

Comment: @Aaron I think we've moved off the IDENTITY() *function* a few comment ago

Comment: [You might find this thread interesting](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/501619-out-order-identity-field-sql2000). Not only because others have observed the same incorrect behavior (fixed by adding `MAXDOP` as I suggested), but also because they point out that the blog post you referenced also states that *most* of those rules apply to SQL Server 2000, but not which ones. I also have a note (sadly under NDA), from someone higher up the MS food chain than the blogger, who is let's say less confident in the blogger's statements (particularly for 2000).

Comment: And remember that not all bug reports are public (exposed on Connect), and bugs against 2000 were never filed against Connect and would never be dealt with there anyway...