# Custom Sort in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp-net-mvc-1

I have a table valued function that I'm calling with a LINQ query.
As I now understand it (as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496306/order-by-in-a-sql-table-valued-function)), the sorting needs to be done outside of the table valued function.  This means, I have to do it in the LINQ query.

I need some assistance with the syntax.  Here's my original call to the function.

```
var sourceQuery = (from f in db.fGameListDataTable(competitionID, eventID,  participantType)
                   select f);
```

I need to take this custom sorting from the SQL query and add it to the LINQ query.

```
Order By 
    CASE 
        WHEN GameType = 'G' THEN '1'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '1' THEN '2'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '2' THEN '3'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '3' THEN '4'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '4' THEN '5'
        WHEN GameType = 'GT' THEN '6'
        WHEN GameType = 'P' THEN '7'
        WHEN GameType = 'FT' THEN '8'   
    END ASC,
    g.GameID ASC
```

**UPDATE**

For a visual reference, here's the table that getting sorted.  Note the order.

[image]

Comment: Do you control the code of the SQL function ? Can't you add an extra column to the returned "table" ?

Comment: Yes, it's my function.   Can you explain what you mean with the extra column?

Comment: Maybe there's something escaping me, but why don't you simply return that extra sorting column from the database function ? Then you can simply sort based on it.

Comment: Actually - just tried your idea.  No that doesn't work, because it's more than just assigning a single value to each column.  For instance, some records can have both a GameType of 'G' and be in GroupNumber '1'.

Comment: You could use the power of expressions in .net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013198/linq-to-sql-dynamic-orderby-case-when/56868434#56868434

Answer (score 4):

You could build a big conditional expression. Unfortunately, it is going to have eight levels of nesting (yuck!)

```
var ordered = (from f in ... select ...)
    .OrderBy(f =>
        f.GameType == 'G' ? 1
    :   f.GroupNumber == '1' ? 2
    :   f.GroupNumber == '2' ? 3
    :   f.GroupNumber == '3' ? 4
    :   f.GroupNumber == '4' ? 5
    :   f.GameType == 'GT'   ? 6
    :   f.GameType == 'P'    ? 7
    :   f.GameType == 'PT'   ? 8
    :   9
    );
```

Comment: I think this may be the solution.  I'll let you know when I can test out out.  Does this affect performance at all?

Comment: @madvora I suspect that you would get the same generated SQL for this (i.e. with a `CASE` expression), so I think the performance is not going to be different.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do something like this:

```
var sourceQuery =
    (from f in db.fGameListDataTable(competitionID, eventID, participantType) select f)
    .OrderBy(f =>
    {
        int sortValue = 0;

        if (f.GameType == "G")
            sortValue = 1;
        else if (f.GroupNumber == "1")
            sortValue = 2;
        else if (f.GroupNumber == "2")
            sortValue = 3;
        else if (f.GroupNumber == "3")
            sortValue = 4;
        else if (f.GroupNumber == "4")
            sortValue = 5;
        else if (f.GameType == "GT")
            sortValue = 6;
        else if (f.GameType == "P")
            sortValue = 7;
        else if (f.GameType == "FT")
            sortValue = 8;

        return sortValue;
    }).ThenBy(f => f.GameID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I still fail to see why you can't use the DB engine to generate that number based on the conditions that you described.

You already gave this as a sample code:

```
Order By 
    CASE 
        WHEN GameType = 'G' THEN '1'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '1' THEN '2'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '2' THEN '3'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '3' THEN '4'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '4' THEN '5'
        WHEN GameType = 'GT' THEN '6'
        WHEN GameType = 'P' THEN '7'
        WHEN GameType = 'FT' THEN '8'   
    END ASC,
    g.GameID ASC
```

Now, while I understand you might not want (or even can) have this exact code inside your table value function (as per your link, the `ORDER BY` needs to be outside the function), I'm pretty near sure you could still have the `CASE` statement to generate an additional column.

I'm not saying that you should ORDER BY on the server though. Simply generate the additional column with the CASE statement, then you will be able to use that column as the LINQ query's order by.

In my earlier comment, when I mentioned adding an extra column, I didn't mean just a sequential column, I meant what I wrote above. That extra column's value would be based on your exact same logic, but would be generated on the server rather than try to implement it in LINQ client side.

Regards

EDIT:

Here's a code snippet showing what it would look like within your table value function:

```
INSERT INTO @Table
  SELECT EventID, GameID, [all you other columns],
    CASE 
        WHEN GameType = 'G' THEN '1'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '1' THEN '2'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '2' THEN '3'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '3' THEN '4'
        WHEN GroupNumber = '4' THEN '5'
        WHEN GameType = 'GT' THEN '6'
        WHEN GameType = 'P' THEN '7'
        WHEN GameType = 'FT' THEN '8'   
    END
  FROM [Whatever you pull your columns from]
```

This is just an example, not the actual code.

Comment: This doesn't work because it's sorting on multiple levels.  Take a look at the first record in my example (gameID 279). According to this logic you would first assign that a 1 because of the game type, then you would overwrite that with a 2 because it's group number 1.  Also you would have multiple records assigned the same value.  How would that help the sort?  The original SQL case logic sorts a small group first, then continues to sort other levels of that small group.

Comment: Like I said, there's something obviously escaping me. I honestly fail to see how your sample SQL CASE is any different. Maybe if you posted the entire original table function, the one that doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by index of the ArrayList:

```
    var periods = new List<string>() 
    { "AM1", "AM2", "0", "1", "2", 
        "3", "4", "5", "5A", "5B", "6", "6X", 
        "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12" };
                
    var bl2 = (from b in db.Tardies 
as IEnumerable<Tardies> select b)
              .ToList()
              .OrderByDescending(b => 
periods.IndexOf(b.period.Trim()));
```

Comment: Loading the entire table in memory to sort it is a *very* expensive and slow idea. A server has far more RAM and CPU cores than any client. I'd say a server can use indexes too, which typically results in 100-1000x faster performance, but this kind of ordering would prevent the server from using indexes

Comment: Thank you! I was using a sql view and I noticed its being slow in both ways local or remote query, but when I join tabled it’s super fast. Do you think it’s because my Sql table View doesn’t have indexing?